# DDD with Microservices and Multiple inputs via REST and Message Queue

Tags: rest, microservices, domain-driven-design, message-queue, business-logic

I have an aggregate root with the business logic in a c# project. Also in the solution is a REST web.api project that passes commands / requests to the aggregate root to do work and handle queries. This is my microservice. Now I want some of my events / commands / request to come of a message queue. I'm considering this:

- Put a console app in the solution to listen for messages from a message queue. *Then reference the aggregate root project in the console app*

Is it a bad pattern to share "microservice business logic" between two services? Because now I have two "services" an api and a console app doing the work. I would have to ensure that when the business logic changes both services are deployed.

Personally I think it is fine to do what I suggest, a good CI/CD pipeline should mitigate that. But are there any other cons I might have missed?

Comment: Why do you want to split the microservice in two? It seems like a bad idea, but maybe you have a good reason for doing it?

Comment: remember to identify the bounded contexts as well, this helps to identify in some fashion if you need to split the original microservice. In your case, the two "services" are an adapter (anti-corruption layer), and the other is an aggregate (service?).

Comment: The microservice started of as restful interfacw, only http inputs. In terms of the onion architecture the Web.api controllers are the application layer. Receiving a message off a queue is another application layer, which needs to talk to the domain layer. It seems a wasteful operation for console application layer to talk to the api.controller application layer. If both application layers live in the same solution they could reference the domain layer.

Comment: Admittedly thought I may have a rethink and they maybe a better to solve my problem. However the idea having http input and message queue input as two things seems to a valid idea. Isn't this what the onion or hexagonal architecture is about?

Comment: It seems to me you are overcomplicating it. REST Api and Messaging are two ways of communicating to the same service (business logic). There is no reason to split the microservice in two because of this. Note that splitting it in two won't give you any real advantage as you will have to deploy both everytime you change their business logic (as it's shared). As I said before, unless you have a very good reason to create two microservices for this, just create one.

Comment: The microservice is split physically but not logically. As depicted in Microsoft example of a microservice architecture. See the ordering microservice
[eShopOnContainers](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/dev/img/eShopOnContainers-architecture.png) from 
from [eShopOnContainers code](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers).
However, I agree with you @FrancescCastells best keep them in the same place unless there is a good reason to physically split it.

Answer (score 2):

For some background I would suggest watching [DDD & Microservices: At Last, Some Boundaries!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPvef9R3k-M) by Eric Evans.

A bounded context is the micro service.  How you surface it is another matter.  What you describe seems to be what I actually do quite frequently.  I have an [Identity & Access](https://github.com/Shuttle/Shuttle.Access) open source project that I'm working on (so depending on when you read this it may be in a different state) that demonstrates this structure.

Internal to an organization one may access the BC either via a service bus or via the web-api.  External parties would utilize only the web-api as messaging should not be exposed.
The web-api either returns data from the *query layer* or sends commands via the service bus (messaging) to the BC functional endpoint.  Depending on the complexity of the system I may introduce an orchestration concern that interacts with multiple BCs.  It is probably a BC in its own right much along the lines of a reporting BC.

Comment: "A bounded context is the micro service" that nails it for me. Thanks for clearing that up.